# Nothing happens when button pressed in calculator application

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Let me begin this with saying that I'm just a beginner at programming. I've just started using Python and I've encountered a problem with a little calculator project that I'm making.

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()

#       ****Sum****

def get_sum(event):
    num1 = int(num1Entry.get())
    num2 = int(num2Entry.get())
    sum = num1 + num2


num1Entry = Entry(root, width=20)
num1Entry.grid(row=0, column=0)

Label(root, text="+").grid(row=0, column=1)

num2Entry = Entry(root, width=20)
num2Entry.grid(row=0, column=2)

equalButton = Button(root, text="=")


equalButton.bind("<Button-1>", get_sum)

equalButton.grid(row=0, column=3)

sumEntry = Entry(root, width=20)
sumEntry.grid(row=0, column=4)


#       ****Minus****

def get_minus(event):
    n1 = int(n1Entry.get())
    n2 = int(n2Entry.get())
    minus = n1 - n2


n1Entry = Entry(root, width=20)
n1Entry.grid(row=1, column=0)

Label(root, text="-").grid(row=1, column=1)

n2Entry = Entry(root, width=20)
n2Entry.grid(row=1, column=2)

equal1Button = Button(root, text="=")

equal1Button.bind("<Button-1>", get_minus)

equal1Button.grid(row=1, column=3)

minusEntry = Entry(root, width=20)
minusEntry.grid(row=1, column=4)


root.mainloop()
```

As some of you may notice, the first part of the code (Sum part) wasn't of my doing. I copied it from somewhere on this site (I don't remember from whom and when exactly) and I wanted to add other functions to it (like '-', '*' or '/'), but I've encountered this problem and I hope that some of you can help me with this.

There are two Entries where I type in the numbers and when I click on the '=' button, it's supposed to show me the result.
However, when I click on the '=' button, nothing happens. It registers the click since the color changes, but the result doesn't appear. I don't know why and I hope that some of you can point out the mistake.

I didn't receive any errors when run it with the console or clicked the button, so I don't know where the mistake actually is.

Please note that I'm still a beginner with Python

Comment: You need to actually describe your specific problem - what you tried, what happens, what you expected to happen, how they differ, what errors you got, etc. This is more important than a lot of verbiage about your beginnerness.

Comment: You need to attach a function to be call when the `Button` is pressed by adding a `command=func` keyword argument to the constructor call. You'll also need to write the function, of course.

Comment: @martineau I did that with `equalButton.bind("<Button-1>", get_sum)`

Answer (score 0):

You did everything right, the function is called and the numbers added. However, you don't have anything to show to the user. If you added `print(sum)` to the end of your function you would see it printed. Or, I assume you want to insert it into the Equals Entry:

```
def get_sum(event=None):
    num1 = int(num1Entry.get())
    num2 = int(num2Entry.get())
    sum = num1 + num2
    print('sum is', sum)
    sumEntry.delete(0, END) # clear
    sumEntry.insert(0, sum)
```

Also, you should use the `command` argument, not `bind`:

```
equalButton = Button(root, text="=", command=get_sum)
```